# Simplify the following expression: $ \frac{(a^3-1)(b^3-1)-1}{ba(a+b)} \;, $ given that $\log(a+b) = \log(ab)$ for $a,b > 0$.

Tags: logarithms

I am a beginner to logarithms, and I need to know how to simplify the following expression:
$$
\dfrac{(a^3-1)(b^3-1)-1}{ba(a+b)} \;,
$$
given that $\log(a+b) = \log(ab)$ for $a,b > 0$.

Comment: The logarithm is a 1-1 function over its domain, so $log(a+b) = log(ab)$ implies $a+b = ab$. Can you use this to start the simplification?

Comment: @Osama Ghani I'm starting

Comment: @Osama Ghani What do you mean by saying 1-1 function? What is the domain of logarithmic functions?

Comment: It just means that if $log(a+b) = log(ab)$ then $(a+b) = ab$.

Comment: That I know, but I am willing to know about that things which I've asked above

Comment: A 1-1 function is one such that if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x = y$. The domain just means what the function can take as an input. So here the domain of $log(x)$ is $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $a,b>0,\ \ln(a+b)=\ln(ab)\iff a+b=ab$

$\displaystyle \frac{(a^3-1)(b^3-1)-1}{ab(a+b)}=\frac{a^3b^3-a^3-b^3}{ab(a+b)}=\frac{(a+b)^3-a^3-b^3}{ab(a+b)}=\frac{3a^2b+3ab^2}{ab(a+b)}=\frac{3ab(a+b)}{ab(a+b)}=3$

Answer (score 1):

Let the answer be some t.then apply log on both sides.we know that log (a/b)=loga-love and log (ab)=loga+logb using both these formulae continue solving.later sustitute the formula for a^3+b^3.

Comment: "loga-love"? Love??

Comment: No logb instead of love